# Weird FileWriter error

Tags: java, bufferedwriter, writer

I have written to files before and never come across this problem, i am utterly confused.

EDIT: Sorry the error is that no lines are being written to the .txt file.

```
   System.out.println(upto); 
   FileWriter writer;
   BufferedWriter write;

   upto = 10;
    try{
    writer = new FileWriter(theFile);    
    write = new BufferedWriter(writer); 
    write.write(upto);
    write.flush();
    write.close();

    }catch(Exception e){
        System.err.println("cant print line");
    }
```

thats is the code that handels writing to the file, the only other code is declaring the file path. No exception error comes up either. I made sure that I was flushing/closing the writer too. Could someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are printing char 10, which is a line feed.  If you want to print the number 10, try

```
write.write(String.valueOf(upto));
```

Comment: In fact he is printing an int, so that is 4 bytes (not just the "relevant" ones). So he is printing `[NUL][NUL][NUL][LF]` (if I got the endianness right). Anyway, +1.

Comment: That's a good point.  The [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html#write%28int%29) is a little ambiguous about it.  It seems to say that the parameter type should be char rather than int.  The method description suggests that the int is cast to char internally.

Comment: Ok, I didn't check the javadoc, I thought it was an overloaded function (with a `write(int)`, a `write(char)`, etc.). My bad.

Answer (score 1):

You are writting a number. It means that you write the bytes of the number (`0x0000000A`), not its character representation `10`. When you open it with notepad or the like, it just finds that it does not contain printable ASCII values and you only see it blank.

Use `write.write(Integer.toString(upto))` to see the difference.